# Fijar el valor de un elemento Select

Tags: html, checkbox

Como puedo hacer para que un select vuelva a su primer valor(Seleccionar) al desactivar un checkbox.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="seleccionar" id="elegir">
<select id="opciones">
    <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
    <option value ="1">Casa</option>
    <option value ="2">Auto</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Y que intentaste hasta el momento. Podes mostrar tu codigo?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="habilitar" id="lista">
<select id="elegir" name="seleccionar">
    <option value="inicio">0</option>
    <option value="1">opcion 1</option>
    <option value="2">opcion 2</option>
</select>

Comment: Toda la info debe ir en la pregunta. Esa es la definicion del select y no dice nada. intentaste algo en el evento del checkbox para volverla a su valor por defecto?

Comment: Y esa última edición?

Comment: No entiendo la forma en la que debo agregar el codigo para que se muestre completo, pero eso es lo que necesito, que el select vuelva a su valor inicial al desmarcar el checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero te sirva...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="habilitar" id="lista" />
        <select id="opciones" required>
            <!-- Yo te recomiendoque utilicés el mensaje con value="", ya que si deseas hacerlo requerido basta agregar el atributo required en el select -->
            <!-- "Haz la prueba que funciona el required con el botón guardar" -->
            <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
            <option value="1">Casa</option>
            <option value="2">Auto</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>

<script>
    // Escuchás el evento click en el input
    document.getElementById("lista").addEventListener("click", function () {
        // Si el check es falso, podrías utilizar también this.checked == false, aunque es lo mismo
        // Podrías realizar de esta manera
        if (!this.checked) document.getElementById("opciones").selectedIndex = 0;
        // Podrías asignando el valor "", que es la opción seleccionar
        if (!this.checked) document.getElementById("opciones").value = "";
    });

    // De esta forma podrías activar el checkbox, cuando hayás seleccionado una opción correcta
    document.getElementById("opciones").addEventListener("change", function () {
        if (document.getElementById("opciones").value >= 1) document.getElementById("lista").checked = true
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Va de maravilla, sin embargo me gustaria que en lugar de resetear cuando activo el checkbox quiero que lo haga cuando lo desmarco, alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Edité el script para que funcione con estos cambios que indicás.

Answer (score -1):

Aqui tienes lo que necesitas

```js
document.getElementById("lista").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(!this.checked){
    document.getElementById("elegir").selectedIndex = 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="habilitar" id="lista"> <select id="elegir" name="seleccionar"> <option value="inicio">0</option> <option value="1">opcion 1</option> <option value="2">opcion 2</option> </select>
```

Lo que he hecho es: coger el `checbox` y darle un evento que escuche si se hizo click o no. En el momento que se produzca tal evento, se verificará si esta marcado o no, es el aprtado de `!this.checked`. Si esta desmarcado te reiniciará el select. 
Pon el codigo de script entre `window.onload = function(){//aqui el codigo}`
Espero que te sirva

Comment: aunque yo no te voté negativo, te explico: responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad pues no explicas en lo absoluto el porque, considera editar esto

Comment: Fantastico lo e aplicado sin embargo me arroja un error y no me genera la funcion que debe realizar el script, el error es el siguiente:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at front.html:2

Comment: @element Gracias por tu comentario. @DanielAscencio acabo de modificar mi codigo de respuesta, creo que te faltaba poner `window.onload`. Verificalo